# How to uncheck radio button programmatically

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, radio-button

i have the below posted radio button, and i would like to know how can i uncheck it programmatically using type script.
i tried the following, i set the value of `averageHeight` to false, but that did not unchecked the radio button.
please let me know how to acheive that

**html**:

```
<div id="idRadioButtonForAverageHeightDivision">
                <input [value]="0" [(ngModel)]="iOperationPasser.averageHeight" name="radioGroupForOperations" type="radio" clrCheckbox  (change)="toggleShowAverageHeight()"  [(checked)]="averageHeight"/>
                    <label id="operation-average-height">
                        {{ "SITE.AREAS_OF_COVERAGE_FOR_THRESHOLD.OPERATION_AVERAGE_HEIGHT" | translate }} 
                        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-icon" (click)="showInformation('SERVICE_DIST_4_AGRI')">
                            <clr-icon shape="help-info" class="is-solid"></clr-icon>
                        </button>
                    </label>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default behavior of the radio input is to be un-unchecked.

You can control the properties of it with bind or something with angular, just access the property `checked` and change it.

like:

```
<input type="radio" value="exm" #radio />


// access the input with local variable on the template
<button (click)="radio.checked=false">
    uncheck
</button>
```

OR ---------------------------

```
<input type="radio" value="exm" [checked]="term" />


// now this is toggling the checked value, so it will check and uncheck - depend on the status
<button (click)="toggle()">
    uncheck
</button>


TS FILE ----------------------
public term: boolean = false

toggle(){
  this.term = !this.term

}
```

AS you want to access the value property, it pretty much looks the same:

```
<input type="radio" [value]="value" />


TS FILE ----------------------
// any change of the value will change it in the template. Since it's not a text input - ngModel is useless .
public value: string = 'Value here'
```

Comment: could you please provide some code?

Comment: Here you are...

Comment: thanks but i need it in type script code not as html!

Comment: Of course, this is just an example, you can access it within a variable on the component.ts file as well, and just set a bind

Comment: Just added the other way

Comment: if we are using `[(ngModel)]` we **not** use "checked", simply change the value of the variable: e.g. `iOperationPasser.averageHeight=null`

Comment: ngModel directive listening to event `input` and bind to property `value`.

We need to change the property `checked`, so ngModel is not the solution.

Comment: would please show me also how to access the attribut [value]??

Comment: @AvivBenShahar, nop, "value" is the value the variable you use in ngModel get when you select the radio button. Check this [fool stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rrxunt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

Comment: @Eliseo 
In your example, you bind value and use ngModel - that's not the way.

ngModel binds the value and update it in two ways.

In this case, we need to change another property - so ngModel isn't the answer.

Comment: @AvivBenShahar,ngModel binds the value to a variable. So, just equal the variable to a null, makes no radio button is select. Futhermore, to know the value selected it's only ask about the variable. I can not see the reason you change the checked property, what about you has severals radio buttons to get a choice? you need change the checked property to all of them! Angular works very well using binding -the really soul of Angular is relation variables in .ts with what you can see in the .html-

Comment: @Eliseo indeed, ngModel binds two-ways the value, but the value in input with type radio - is the label! not if it checked. You can wrap all the radio buttons with one element and give them the same name so only one can be selected. then -ngModel will be useful.